# Can I ExecuteBundle without SetPipelineState at bundle?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, directx-12

I created a some bundle command lists:

```
IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vtxBuff.m_view);
IASetIndexBuffer(&idxBuff.m_view);
DrawIndexedInstanced(idxBuff.m_nCount, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

and not called SetPipelineState because shaders may be difference at run time.
When I fill direct command list, I try to set common states, and execute bundle:

```
pCmdList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
pCmdList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(m_pRootSignature.p);
pCmdList->SetPipelineState(m_pPipelineState.p);
pCmdList->SetDescriptorHeaps(1, &m_cbHeap.p);
for(int n...)
{
  pCmdList->ExecuteBundle(commands[n].m_cmdList.m_pCommandList.p);
}
```

but, how as written at microsoft docs:"*If no PSO is specified in the call, a default initial state is used.*", I recive

```
D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandList::ExecuteBundle: Error is from this API call recorded in the bundle: ID3D12CommandList::DrawIndexedInstanced: No pipeline state has been set in this command list.  The runtime will use a default no-op pipeline state. [ EXECUTION ERROR #1045: COMMAND_LIST_PIPELINE_STATE_NOT_SET]
```

Can I change default pipline state on command list or other ways execute bundle command lists without call SetPipelineState ?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12graphicscommandlist-executebundle):

"Bundles inherit all state from the parent command list on which `ExecuteBundle` is called, except the pipeline state object and primitive topology."

So you need to call the `SetPipelineState` inside a bundle. If you plan to support multiple pipeline states in runtime, maybe consider dropping bundles all together.